# Rewrite/change WordPress search mechanism

Tags: php, wordpress, search, hook

I've been looking for a way to change the WordPress searching mechanism. My database has several custom tables, which I want to take into account when searching the site. Also, I wan't to implement a levenshtein function for coming up with lines like "Did you mean [another term]?" when somebody makes a spelling error.

Is there a hook, action or function I can implement or change to allow these kind of functions? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace the WordPress search with your own search, by replacing your own search box with a custom search box which then calls a function which uses one of these searches. This will allow you  to replace the default wordpress search without modifying the core files.

Three possible options would be:

- [MySQL Match Against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

I had to do a similar thing for my own WordPress site. I originally went with MySQL match against, but I have since switched to Sphinx. I ran into serious speed issues using MySQL match against, although those problems vanished when I switched to Sphinx.

Comment: I know how to build a search mechanism, my question was actually how to implement it in WordPress with the correct flow, hooks and actions. What do you advise on that?

Comment: I'm uncertain sure how to do modify the wordpress search function itself - which is why I suggested replacing it instead.    

to replace it, you would need to use "add_filter('the_content', 'yourFilter'")

Comment: I'm sorry for downvoting this but here is the reason: If you had any knowledge of Wordpress, you'd know that modifying the core is the worst thing you could do, this is not a solution at all, not even a technique, just an insight on other replacement technologies...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin: I didn't mean for the OP to modify the core files. The intention was to just replace the search box on the wordpress sites with a new form which would call one of these functions instead of the wordpress search. You would never touch the core wordpress files at all.