# Include postmeta in WordPress search

Tags: wordpress, search

How can I tell the default WordPress search function to also look at the postmeta data?

For example, I have a postameta key called 'item_number' and if someone searches '113', I'd like for it to check the key's value as well as the post content.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This site provided the answer I was looking for: 
http://flav36rs.com/2010/03/15/extend-wordpress-search-to-include-custom-post-meta/

There are some helpful comments below the tutorial worth looking at if you run into problems.

---

EDIT:

The above link is dead.

Ultimately, I ended up writing a complete custom search query using [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to build the query I needed.

Comment: Sorry to bother this late, but the link you have provided is not working. can you please check this? Regards.

Comment: See the other link I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to include meta values inside your searching scope: you can hook into [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) and add a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) like this:

Inside your *functions.php*:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_9224493_adjust_search_query');
function so_9224493_adjust_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) { //the !is_admin() boolean ensures that this does not affect your dashboard
        $meta_query_arguments = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'item_number', //this is where you would put your meta key
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_arguments);
    };
}
```

The only problem with this route is that it will **include** the meta query so that your search query will only match posts that include the search term inside the Title/Content/Excerpt *and* the meta field, which might not be preferable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace your Wordpress search function with your own. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538098/rewrite-change-wordpress-search-mechanism).

Comment: I'm left with the same question as the user in the referred post: What would be the right WordPress hooks/functions to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple workaround: put all meta values you want to be searchable into `post_exerpt` field (use [save_post action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)), so they will be found without any search modifications.